# Which is the oldest language in the World?

Tags: ancient-history, language

I want to know which are the oldest languages in the world? And within those, which is still in use?

Comment: Written or spoken?

Comment: In any ways? It's better, if it categorized!

Comment: Including [primates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_language#Primate_language) or not? Wikipedia may contain all the answers, even categorized in many dimensions.

Comment: In a Chomskean sense, all languages.

Comment: [The Jacquard loom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquard_loom) and the [Analytical engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_engine)... ^_~

Comment: The [FAQ](http://history.stackexchange.com/faq) discourages questions that can be answered by a simple google search.

Comment: Hebrew seems to be an examples of a resurrected language. Perhaps this is oldest in the sense that it is largely unchanged.

Comment: Clearly, Language of the Birds. [Dr John Carter/Steve Jobs said so](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Librarian_%28franchise%29)

Comment: A problem with this is that we don't know that the other branches of Homo didn't speak (Erectus, Ergaster, etc)

Answer (score 9):

I think a simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Which%20is%20the%20oldest%20language%20in%20the%20World?&aq=f&oq=Which%20is%20the%20oldest%20language%20in%20the%20World?&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will reveal the answer.  There is a fairly detailed answer at [Ask A Linguist](http://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/oldest.cfm); this is particularly nice because it examines some of the issues that make the question difficult to answer. Either Sumerian or Egyptian is the oldest written form, and that the answer for spoken languages is undefined.
[Yahoo](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071215031604AA7Ua9S) takes a different approach to the question of written languages, and I think their answer is splendid. "All spoken languages today are equally old." The author also notes that Egyptian competes with Sumerian for the title of oldest written language.   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_first_written_accounts) concentrates on written sources and asserts Sumerian.

Comment: Essentially my answer, so +1 for being correct. :-)

Comment: As much as I like a good wiki entry (and I do - when wiki's good, it's gooooood), the better reference was the "Ask a Linguist" - the answer really should be pared down to a summary of that link, and a corroboration with the well cited wikipedia page. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Languages are not static things; they evolve with the times and the needs of the users. For example, you could try to say English is [about 1500 years old](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English), but modern speakers cannot understand English from that long ago (unless trained to do so), so it just wouldn't be true.

Part of the definition of a language is that people who speak (or write) it can understand each other. I personally can't even comprehend Shakespearean English, so for me the language isn't really any more than 400 or so years old. Icelandic, which has a reputation for being the most conservative known language, is [in a similar situation](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1276/8124) to my own Shakespeare with its 800 year old sagas. So **probably no living language is significantly older than 700 years.**

If instead you try to count modern languages and their predecessors together for the purposes of determining age, then just about all languages are likely the same age. While [it does happen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language#History), it is exceedingly rare for languages to just sprout up with no predecessors. So **by this definition nearly all human languages are the same age.**

Comment: No living language older than about 400 years ? I suggest you make that 800 years. Icelandic has hardly changed from Old Norse over about 800 years.

Comment: @Tonny - This seems like the kind of statement that people would like to exaggerate, so I went over to the Linguistics stack and looked into it. The accepted answer to [this question on Icelandic's conservatisim](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/what-explains-the-icelandic-language-conservatism) explains that this is real, but indeed highly exaggerated. For instance, modern Icelanders are no better at reading those 800 year old sagas than I am at Shakespeare. So yes, you might be able to say it is an "older" language than English, but that age is not 800 years.

Comment: @Tonny - ...tell you what, I'll split the difference and give you 700. :-)

Comment: @TED Fine with me, sounds about right :-)